# Ошибка Permission denied при восстановлении данных из дампа на osx

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
MacBook-Air:~ postgres$ psql >/Users/darya/Documents/postgres_backups/dump.sql
-bash: /Users/darya/Documents/postgres_backups/dump.sql: Permission denied
```

Пытаюсь восстановить базу данных из дампа

Но появляется ошибка Permission denied

Работаю на os X

Доступ к файлу пользователю postgres открыла

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: а так? `cat /Users/darya/Documents/postgres_backups/dump.sql | psql -U DBUSER DBNAME`

Comment: `Пытаюсь восстановить` - определённо нет. Пытаетесь переписать файл выводом команды psql - да.

Comment: Может я вообще совсем не так всё делаю? У меня есть файл damp.sql и мне нужно, чтобы данные из него скопировались в бд dbBank

Comment: 1) вы работаете в терминале? 2) какие права установлены на этом файле?

Comment: да, работаю в терминале, права на чтение и запись для postgres

Comment: если на файл установлены "права на чтение и запись для postgres" то вопрос - для "остальных" пользователей какие права?

Comment: для остальных тоже чтение и запись

Comment: ну, надеюсь там действительно `-rw-rw-rw-`. попробуйте так `psql -U DBUSER DBNAME` и в постгресовой консоли `\i /Users/darya/Documents/postgres_backups/dump.sql `

Comment: пишет command not found ( мне кажется, что я где-то туплю

Comment: `which psql` ??

Comment: `MacBook-Air:~ postgres$` у пользователя postgres есть права на чтение и запись файла, но нет доступа к нему. давайте это подтвердим, скажите от имени postgres `ls -la /Users/darya/Documents/postgres_backups`

Comment: в общем у postgres не было доступа к корневой папке Documents, я дала доступ. но теперь пишет, что команда psql не найдена. сейчас выглядет так psql dbBank < /Users/darya/Documents/postgres_backups/dump.sql